# Its possible to connect two android applications installed on the same device with same SQLite database (local database)?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have two android applications "App1" and "App2", these two mobile applications will installed on the same device. App1 will insert data to local database created on the device (SQLite database) and  "App2" will read data from the same database. Its possible ?

Comment: Of course, it is possible. Make sure you insert data before you read it though.

Comment: Use content providers

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not. DB of each app is isolated and unless you are rooted, apps cannot see each other private data. The only way to share DB is to make one app expose it via content provider. you need to then secure content provider access so only other app can bind.